# Remove all nodes which don’t lie in any path with sum>= k

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I was reading the topic here and reading the code- http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-all-nodes-which-lie-on-a-path-having-sum-less-than-k/

However I am stuck at a point. In the following functions of the code:

```
struct Node *pruneUtil(struct Node *root, int k, int *sum)
{
    // Base Case
if (root == NULL)  return NULL;

// Initialize left and right sums as sum from root to
// this node (including this node)
int lsum = *sum + (root->data);
int rsum = lsum;

// Recursively prune left and right subtrees
root->left = pruneUtil(root->left, k, &lsum);
root->right = pruneUtil(root->right, k, &rsum);

// Get the maximum of left and right sums
*sum = max(lsum, rsum);

// If maximum is smaller than k, then this node
// must be deleted
if (*sum < k)
{
    free(root);
    root = NULL;
}

return root;
}

// A wrapper over pruneUtil()
struct Node *prune(struct Node *root, int k)
{
    int sum = 0;
return pruneUtil(root, k, &sum);
}
```

I have following two queries:

1. In the function *prune, we call the function pruneUTIL send the *address* of sum and then in function pruneUTIL, we use *sum everywhere.Why do we send the address? What's the point of using address of sum?
2. Why don't we send simple the integer *sum*?
3. Why do we calculate max of lsum and rsum?

Can anybody solve the query?

Comment: for your second question. I think it's okay to use pass-by-reference too. This code is a little bie C-style, which is fine. Though it's better to use reference in CPP code IMO.

Comment: http://ideone.com/nqyI9N here is the code where I tried sending the integer values. It didn't work.

Comment: nah, you are passing by value here; struct Node *pruneUtil(struct Node *root, int k, int sum)

Comment: Yes. I got confused between the two. But the point is why is this code wrong?

Comment: you want to change 'sum' when you call pruneUtil. Pass-by-value could not achieve that. Pass-by-reference can achieve this. I suggest you try to refresh CPP and C concept about pass-by-reference and pointers. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The point of using the pointer to the sum variable is that the variable sum will be modifiable. If you just send one sum then the change in value will not be reflected when the function returns . Eg

```html
    int main()
    {
      int v=1;
      goot(v);
      gootp(&v)l
    }
    void goot(int val)
    {
      val=10;
    }
    void gootp(int * val)
    {
      *val=10;
    }
```

After goot return the value of v will not be 10 it will remain to be  1
but when a call to gootp is made the value will be modified to 10.

And here we want the change to be reflected as for each node we want sum to be the maximum of all the paths it can take to reach any leaf + the value calculated from root to the node we could have simply have returned the value but here we are deleting nodes so we need to return the nodes if they are null then left/right child need to be modified as only one thing can be returned so we use pointer to this variable

2. So we do not send the variable sum because when the function pruneUtil return for left and right child of a node then the value of sum calculated for those subtrees would be lost. So that we can compare the sum of the path because we need to add the value of nodes below the node to calculate the sum of the path. If we just send a variable its changes could not be seen in the parent function(as we can not return the value as it is being used to return the node).
3. We calculate max of left and right because when for a node there are two paths going towards leaf one via its left and other via its right child (these paths further will divide) so if either of these paths have sum value > k then we need not to delete the node. So we take max of left and right its done for each node so for each node we get the maximum value of the path from root to leaf.

Comment: Thank you. I completely understood the concept. :)